# No discard annotation in Java

Tags: java, annotations, sonarqube, static-analysis

My team and I just came across a bug in our codebase because we were ignoring a return value of an immutable structure: https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/pull/229.

I'd like to annotate methods such as [`Trie.put`](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/commit/08bb57f57bcd1c2fc1d6a86bb012680aab52e0e8#L35) to instruct the user to not discard the value (à la `[[nodiscard]]` in C++17) to prevent future issues.

We're using SonarQube and are able to turn on checks from FindBugs and others, but it would be best if the code didn't compile like when using `@Override` on a method not present in the base class. I've tried `@CheckReturnValue` and it gives me a warning in the IntelliJ IDE, but nothing prevents shipping such code.

What other alternatives can we explore to introduce more checks at compile time?

Comment: SonarQube will not prevent you from compiling code.

Comment: In fact, SonarJava _requires_ compiled code to run.